# NPM ERROR, NEXT.JS ERROR can not use npm run dev

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, node-modules

```
> @ dev C:\Users\Mustafa\Desktop\React&Next\insta-2.0
> next dev

'Next\insta-2.0\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Mustafa\Desktop\next\dist\bin\next'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)        
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-13T15_27_45_466Z-debug.log
```

I am using npm run dev and it gives me this error and I don't understand what this error is about if any of you could help me solve this I would really appreciate it

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the `root` directory of Your `next project` and run this commands in `terminal`:

```
npm install next react react-dom
```

after

```
npm run dev
```

Or if You are using `VSCode` open Your `next project` in `Visual Studio Code`, run the integrated terminal **(Ctrl+`)** and enter the above commands.

It's should works now ;-)